# Lua package submission to ctan

Tags: packages, miktex, texlive, lua, ctan

I have created some useful stuff for Mathematics with lua. So far I have  the following files.

1. my package.sty
2. file1.lua
3. file2. lua
4. readme
5. documentation.tex
6. documentation. pdf

The read me file includes link to gpl license and some license information.  Here are my specific questions

1. Where shoud I include version number? May I include it in sty file or read me file?
2. I will put all the above files in single folder, zip it and upload it to ctan. Is that okay? Should I include some additional files.
3. Once ctan accepts my package, will it be automatically available to miktex and/or texlive? Or are there different procedures for submissions?
4. Will I be able to edit the package after submission to ctan? Are updates get automatically reflected on miktex and or texlive?

I searched related questions on tex.stackexchange.com but couldn't find specific answers to these questions. Thats why I am posting this question. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [What is good practice when preparing a package for CTAN?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/25116)

Comment: ctan have guidelines here https://ctan.org/help/upload-pkg?lang=en

Comment: Should I put lua files in different folder? Also if I want to make lua files available for all tex files on my local computer,  where should I place them. I have miktex and Windows 7 operating system.

Comment: It may be useful to add a note to the readme or the CTAN upload comment field about the role of the `.lua` files and where they need to go in the TeX tree. I think TeX live usually moves `.lua` files to the `doc/` tree unless otherwise instructed (or unless it is absolutely clear that the `.lua` file needs to go elsewhere). See for example https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2018-November/042741.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the questions in order:

1. It's up to you where you put the version number, but it's useful it both the `.sty` and `.lua` files contain some information on release number for debugging
2. CTAN require some documentation, ideally a `README` and a PDF containing details; for TeX Live in particular you need to provide the source for the PDF too.
3. MiKTeX and TeX Live take most of what gets uploaded to CTAN: the key thing is that the license is provided and is free (for TeX Live at least; MiKTeX is more permissive)
4. Uploads to CTAN are fine provided you use the same email address to identify you. MiKTeX and TeX Live update (semi)-automatically from CTAN, so once youare sorted it's easy.

Comment: So there is no separate routine for texlive and miktex. Right? Should license be provided separately or link in read me file is sufficient?

Comment: @user61681 No separate submission, no. As long as the license is clear, you don't have to provide the text itself.

Comment: Where should license information be provided? In read me file?

Comment: @user61681 it's really up to you, but it's quite common to have a line in each source as that way there is no ambiguity. For example, I put it at the top of my `.dtx` files, as do the LaTeX team.